# Little bit complexed condition SELECT in SQLite 3.7.12

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I had a table named "calls" with following records

```
id      number
1998    1234
1999    5678
2000    567890
2001    567890
2002    567890
2003    567890
2004    567890
2005    5645
2006    5612
```

I would like to SELECT all the records with condition combined with following 2 needs:

1. number must be "567890"
2. "id" is in sub SELECT of number=567890, but not the max id. in this case, "2004 567890" is the exception.

so the result will be:

```
id      number
2000    567890
2001    567890
2002    567890
2003    567890
```

I had tried this:

```
select * FROM calls where number='567890' ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1;
```

which works on the SQLiteSpy, but this is not working in Android terminal command, which shows me "Error: near "ORDER": syntax error.", the one I tried is:

```
sqlite3 database.db "select * FROM calls where number='567890' ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1;"
```

And sometimes, the amount of records with number=567890 may vary, so the "LIMIT" in the above statement is not effective, if it can use wild code like * in REG search which can match all of them?

Comment: Show the exact error message.

Comment: is there an `_id` column?

Comment: That command cannot generate a syntax error. Did you use copy+paste to show the actual command you were using?

Comment: @CL.  shows me "Error: near "ORDER", when I use delete, instead of Select *, it seems select is good. but I need to some how change to delete as well.

Comment: @njzk2 actually the id is _id column, is this difference? sorry, I am really a newbie.

Comment: DELETE works differently; maybe you should ask a new question for that.

Comment: `"Error: near "ORDER", when I use delete` probably because there is no such thing as order in a delete query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
select c.*
from calls c
where c.number = '567890' and
      c.id <> (select max(c2.id) from calls c2 where c2.number = c.number);
```

Comment: Thanks, even I didn't know what's exactly the c.* means, but it works. further question, if I change this to DELETE, it produce an error "Error: near "c": syntax error", how can I make this statement work with DELETE as well?

Comment: You can just do `delete from calls` and change the subsequent `c.` to `calls.`.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#limitoffset) says:

> If the LIMIT expression evaluates to a negative value, then there is no upper bound on the number of rows returned.

So to use a LIMITless OFFSET:

```
SELECT * FROM calls WHERE number = '567890' ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT -1 OFFSET 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the "limit -1" trick, but when I use this on the SQLite3 command, it still shows me "Error: near "ORDER": syntax error. I am under kitkat 4.4.4 cm11, I believe it use SQLite 3.7.12. Any further advice? thank you.